# How to change dynamically the xib of a UIVIewController

Tags: iphone, ios, nib, xib, viewcontroller

I have an UIVIewController "controller1" for instance. This controller is instanciated with initWithNibName... with "file1.xib".
I want to dynamically change the xib file of my "controller1" to "file2.xib"

To resume :

"controller1" <-> "file1.xib"
and I want to dynamically have :
"controler1" <-> "file2.xib"

How can I do this ?

Hope I was clear.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by switching the xib. Why do this? We may be able to provide an alternative

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to change views in a UIViewController just just use this code:

```
NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"file2" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
self.view = aView;
```

Comment: What about low memory warnings causing the view to be unloaded - how would your view controller know where to reload it's view from again - the new xib or the old one (hint: it would load the old one)

Comment: Ok I use this, I works nice.
It is just needed to retain the original view object to use it later.

Thanks !

Comment: @deanWombourne can always have a boolean to say the view has switched.

Answer (score 1):

I have two responses :

1) Why - this isn't something that you would normally do - what makes this case special? In fact, I'm going to edit this to be more emphatic --> **DON'T DO IT** <-- there will be all sorts of dependencies in UIViewController that you don't know about (for example if there is a low memory warning and your view controller unloads it's view, which xib would it load the view from when it had to display it again?)

2) **If you desperately had to** you can remove the view and reload it though [NSBundle's loadNibNamed:owner:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000401-CJBHHDFC) passing in the new xib and self as the owner.

Comment: yeah, you should link file2.xib to another UIViewController, and load that up.

Comment: It can be the same class of view controller - just not the same instance!

Comment: Ah yes, [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"aNib" bundle:nil];