# objective c open new xib conditionally

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, xib

Hello all I have 5 xib files with a if statement:

```
enter code here
if(results == @"1")
{
    //open xib1
}else if(results == @"2")
{
    //Open xib2
}else if(results ==@"3"){
    //Open xib3
}else if(results ==@"4"){
    //open xib4
}else if(results ==@"5"){
    //open xib5
}
```

I dont know how to open a new xib and close the old one, I am new to objective c sorry.
Sorry this is for a iPad I guess it does not matter if I open a new xib or show a xib over the top of the main one.

Thanks!

so this will work?

```
if(results == @"1")
{
    NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results1" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = aView;
}else if(results == @"2")
{
    NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results2" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = aView;
}else if(results ==@"3"){
    NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results3" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = aView;
}else if(results ==@"4"){
    NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results4" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = aView;
}else if(results ==@"5"){
    NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Results5" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *aView = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = aView;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498822/how-to-change-dynamically-the-xib-of-a-uiviewcontroller

Comment: Where is this code?  What platform (OSX/iOS)?